# Order of Ш (Sha)

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

To prove the BSD conjecture, one has to know about 'the finiteness of the Shafarevich Tate group'. But, an example of an elliptic curve of rank 2 (whose Sha group $Ш(E/\mathbb{Q})$ is finite) is not yet known.

Is there any example of an elliptic curve of rank 2 such that $p$-primary components of Ш are trivial for $p$ outside a finite set of primes?.
In particular, $Ш(E/\mathbb{Q})[p]$ is trivial for $p$ $\neq$ 2, 3, 5, 7.

Comment: One way of typing the letter Ш is to use http://russian.typeit.org/.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there are no such examples known. In fact, with the current technology, the two questions are more or less equally hard. That's because for any given prime $p$, you can, in principle, establish finiteness of $Ш(E/\mathbb{Q})[p^\infty]$ algorithmically by performing $p^n$-descent for higher and higher $n$, until the upper bound on the rank of $Ш(E/\mathbb{Q})[p^n]$ stabilises. Of course, we cannot prove a priori that this would ever happen, but in practice, if you knew finiteness of $p$-primary parts of sha outside a finite set of primes, you would run your computer to do $p^n$-descent for the remaining primes, until you establish finiteness for this finite set, too.

Comment: Dear Alex, Thanks for your comment.